# Win2008 - Use task scheduler to open a password protected web page every n minutes?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I already know how to use task scheduler to open a web page that does not require login (eg http://google.com).

But is it possible to open a web page that requires a login and automatically enter the login data?

eg /protected/page.aspx which redirects to /protected/login.aspx?returnUrl=page.aspx

Or is there a better way to do this than task scheduler?

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Just to open a web page on the same server. Literally a ping/keep-alive page, but its password protected because it shows some stats.

Comment: Might it be easier to just create a separate page that doesn't have any valuable data and thus doesn't need to be password protected?

Comment: Why do you need to enter the password? If it asks for the password, then it's surely alive.

Answer (score 0):

There are rather enormous security implications here - I really wouldn't recommend this - but if the page uses basic authentication (i.e. it sends an HTTP 401 header, the browser sends credentials, then it proceeds to the page), you can authenticate by going to `http(s)://username:password@example.com`. Most browsers do give you a warning first though, asking if you're sure you want to send your username and password to the site. Furthermore, it appears that IE specifically does not support this, so you would have to use another browser like Firefox, which does.